# How do run code on the same thread with System.Threading.Timer c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a application which should run a method every few seconds but wait until the previous run is finished. I have solved that by disabling the timer before the metod runs as in the code below. I have some doubts that another thread is invoked from time to time anyway. I would like to run everything on the same thread. Any ideas on how to do that using system.threading.timer?

Thanks in advance.

```
  timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
  {

    Console.WriteLine("*** Running Code *** ");
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

    timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

    MyMethod();

    timer.Change(periodTimeSpanGet,periodTimeSpanGet);

    Console.WriteLine("*** Code Finished Code *** ");
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

}
, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpanGet);
```

`

Comment: Why "on the same thread"? What benefit does this bring? Timer callbacks happen in the threadpool, so not necessarily on the same thread.

Comment: Use `SynchronizationContext` Post or Send (assuming the thread you're trying to marshal onto is not the thread pool and supports this)

Comment: It seems that your problem is the unwanted concurrency (overlapping executions), and not that each execution may happen in a different thread. A solution for the second problem is also a solution for the first problem, but may not be an optimal one.

Comment: Thank you. How do I solve the unwanted concurrency?

Comment: You can solve the problem of unwanted concurrency easily by awaiting a [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay), or the `WaitAsync` method of a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) instantiated with initial count = 1. Your question has already good answers for what you want, but not for what you ask in the title!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just run an async loop?

```
 while(someCondition)
 {
      DoTheWork();
      await Task.Delay(someAmountOfTime);
 }
```

If timing is of importance, you can run a [`StopWatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8) to measure the passage of time and do some calculations to figure out what `someAmountOfTime` should be. Otherwise, just use a constant value.

Comment: This solution does not guarantee a constant interval between executions. To make it constant (assuming that each job lasts less time than the delay) you should create the `Task.Delay` task before executing the job, and `await` the task afterwards.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Well yes, but OPs existing solution used a fixed interval *between* jobs, so this is approximately the same. I love the idea of setting a delay off before the job though. Nice.

Comment: @You are right. Your solution matches the OP's current setup. I believe that they would prefer a constant interval though. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a shared semaphore to limit concurrent executions of your method to 1 at a time. Instantiate the semaphore once before starting the timer, and reuse it in every execution of the timer.

When the method starts, you'll want to wait for the semaphore to become available. At the end of the method, you'll want to release the semaphore. This ensures only one execution occurs at a time between the wait and the release.

Using a semaphore is better than a lock because it allows you to supply a timeout, a maximum amount of time to wait before giving up.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/threading/semaphore-and-semaphoreslim